# Removing a directory from local Repository without affecting remote repository - Make git ignore the directory

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

Suppose I have the following directory structure

```
DirA (git Repository)
  |_DirB
  |_DirC
  |_DirD
     |_DirE
     |_DirF
```

I currently have my git Repository to something that looks like Above.
Everything in my repository has been pushed up.Now I would like to remove the folder `DirF`. I would like to remove this folder without git telling me that changes have been made and that the files of this folder do not exist.I simply want to tell git to ignore or stop tracking this folder and its contents. I have tried several things however I might be doing something wrong due to which I cant accomplish this task. Here are the two things I tried so far

```
Attempt:1
git update-index --assume-unchanged DirA/DirD/DirF
fatal: Unable to mark file DirD/DirF
```

I then tried placing a .gitignore in `DirD` which had `DirF/` only inside it. However that does not seem to work.
Any suggestions. The folder DirF is currently being tracked and has been pushed up to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

--assume-unchaged won't work on directories, but should work on files. You should use it on all the files in DirF.

Comment: I place './DirD/DirF' however I am still getting complaints about the missing files

Comment: I'm sorry because I misunderstood your question when posting my answer. .gitignore won't work in this condition.

Comment: I've found a solution. --assume-unchaged won't work on directories, but should work on files. You should use it on all the files in DirF.

Answer (score 1):

I expand upon @DDoSolitary 's excellent answer.

Practically, when setting to ignore, before file deletion, the files can be iterated with `find`:

```
find ./DirD/DirF -type f -name "*" \
 -exec git update-index --assume-unchanged {} \;
 -exec rm {} \;
```

registered and then deleting each one.

Going back the other way, to make the files be no longer ignored, `find` cannot be used because the files are not their.

However, [the git-update-index doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) says:

> To see which files have the "assume unchanged" bit set, use:
>    (see git-ls-files[1]).

```
git ls-files -v
```

resulting in something line

```
H <not ignored file including path>
h <ignored file including path>
```

where the letter is not important, only the case (lower for ignored, upper for not ignored).

[The git-ls-files doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) say:

> -v
>       Similar to -t, but use lowercase letters for files that are marked as assume unchanged (see git-update-index[1]).

So it is possible to automate the un-ignore action.